# Partial string search between two files using AWK

Tags: bash, awk

I have been trying to re-write an egrep command using awk to improve performance but haven't been successful. The egrep command performs a simple case insensitive search of the records in file1 against (partial matches in) file2. Below is the command and sample output.

file1 contains:

```
Abc
xyz
123
blah
hh
a,b
```

file2 contains:

```
abc de
xyz
123
456
blah
test1
abdc
abc,def,123
kite
a,b,c
```

Original command :
`egrep -i -f file1 file2`

Original (egrep) command output :

```
$ egrep -i -f file1 file2
abc de
xyz
123
blah
abc,def,123
a,b,c
```

I would like to use AWK to rewrite the command to do the same operation. I have tried the below but it is performing a full record match and not partial like grep does.

Modified command in awk :
`awk 'NR==FNR{a[tolower($0)];next} tolower($0) in a' file1 file2`

Modified command (awk) output:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[tolower($0)];next} tolower($0) in a' file1 file2
xyz
123
blah
```

This excludes the records which had partial matches for the string "abc". Any help to fix the awk command please? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why egrep? If records in file1 are not regular expressions fgrep would be far more performant

Comment: egrep is the old code which is quite slow. I would like to use an alternative code in awk to  make it run faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `index` like this for a partial literal match:

```
awk '
NR == FNR {
  needles[tolower($0)]
  next
}
{
  haystack = tolower($0)
  for (needle in needles) {
    if (index(haystack, needle)) {
      print
      break
    }
  }
}' file1 file2
```

Comment: Thanks @oguz - this worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I would be a bit surprised that it's significantly faster than `egrep` but you can try this:

```bash
$ awk 'NR==FNR {r=r ((r=="")?"":"|") tolower($0);next} tolower($0)~r' file1 file2
abc de
xyz
123
blah
abc,def,123
```

Explanation: first build the `r1|r2|...|rn` regular expression from the content of `file1` and store it in `awk` variable `r`. Then print all lines of `file2` that match it, thanks to the `~` match operator.

If you have GNU `awk` you can use its `IGNORECASE` variable instead of `tolower`:

```bash
$ awk -v IGNORECASE=1 'NR==FNR{r=r ((r=="")?"":"|") $0;next} $0~r' file1 file2
abc de
xyz
123
blah
abc,def,123
```

And with GNU `awk` it could be that forcing the type of `r` to `regexp` instead of `string` leads to better performance. The manual says:

> Given that you can use both regexp and string constants to describe
> regular expressions, which should you use?  The answer is "regexp
> constants," for several reasons:
> ...
> It is more efficient to use regexp constants.  'awk' can note that
> you have supplied a regexp and store it internally in a form that
> makes pattern matching more efficient.  When using a string
> constant, 'awk' must first convert the string into this internal
> form and then perform the pattern matching.

In order to do this you can try:

```bash
$ awk -v IGNORECASE=1 'NR==FNR {s=s ((s=="")?"":"|") $0;next}
    FNR==1 && NR!=FNR {r=@//;sub(//,s,r);print typeof(r),r} $0~r' file1 file2
regexp Abc|xyz|123|blah|hh
abc de
xyz
123
blah
abc,def,123
```

(`r=@//` forces variable `r` to be of type `regexp` and `sub(//,s,r)` does not change this)

Note: just like with your `egrep` attempts, the lines of `file1` are considered as regular expressions, not simple text strings to search for. So, if one line in `file1` is `.*`, all lines in `file2` will match, not just the lines containing substring `.*`.

Comment: If you have GNU `awk` and if you could time the two versions (`r`as a string and `r` as a `regexp`), I would be very interested in the results...